# Step in proof that if $\Bbb{E}(X_n)\to\mu$ and Var$(X_n)\to0$ then $X_n \overset{P}{\to} \mu$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}Var(X_n)=0$.
>
> Show that if  $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Bbb{E}(X_n)=\mu \in \Bbb{R}$ then $X_n \overset{P}{\to} \mu$.

So my teacher solved this problem in class and there is a step which seems reasonable but I can't see how to prove it or how to even be sure it is true.

She says that

$$\{|X_n - \Bbb{E}(X_n)+\Bbb{E}(X_n)-\mu|>\epsilon\}\subset \{|X_n - \Bbb{E}(X_n)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}\cup \{|\Bbb{E}(X_n)-\mu|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\} $$

And then the proof follows easily. However Im not being able to see how that event inclusion is true, and how could I prove it. How do you prove event inclusions generally?

Comment: Would you be able to prove that $$\{|X_n - \Bbb{E}(X_n)|\le\tfrac12\epsilon\}\cap \{|\Bbb{E}(X_n)-\mu|\le\tfrac12\epsilon\}\subseteq\{|X_n - \Bbb{E}(X_n)+\Bbb{E}(X_n)-\mu|\le\epsilon\} $$ instead?

Comment: I see the idea, but I don't know were to start! What would be an element of the intersection in the left hand side?

Comment: An $\omega$ such that $|X_n(\omega) - \mathbb{E}X_n | \le \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ and $|\mathbb{E}X_n - \mu | \le \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$.

Comment: Forget "the idea", whatever it means, and pick any $\omega$ in the intersection in the LHS. Then...